# What does root directive in nginx refer to when it is assigned a static folder?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nginx

I have a nodejs app served with nginx for static files. On reading the sites_available of nginx, I saw root was assigned a static file serving folder (public folder to be exact). What does this mean?
My configuration looks like

```
server {
  server_name mysite.mydomain.com;
  root /var/www/mysite/public/;
  index index.html index.htm;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/mysite.access.log;
  error_log  /var/log/nginx/mysite.error.log;
  underscores_in_headers on;

  recursive_error_pages on;
  error_page 503 @maintenance;

  if (-f $document_root/system/maintenance.html) {
    return 503;
  }

  location @maintenance {
    error_page 405 = /system/maintenance.html;
    rewrite  ^(.*)$  /system/maintenance.html break;
  }

  location ~ ^/(js|css|images|media|system)/ {
    autoindex off;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    expires 4w;
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html @proxy;
  }

  location @proxy {
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:7485;
  }
}
```

Can any one explain this to me? I searched through the nginx documentation and didn't find any answer to my queries.

Answer (score 0):

The `root` directive sets the base path for the requests. In other words, it is used to translate http request paths into file system paths.

For example, with your `root` set as `/var/www/` under the `server` directive, if a file `http://www.example.com/image.jpg` is requested, it's path will be translated to `/var/www/image.jpg`

More details can be found here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root

Comment: yes that was my problem. If the root is set to public folder won't the other routes that is to be handled by nodejs server be mis-routed?
And I also didn't find anything about @proxy, can you help me out with that one to?

Comment: @suman What are you trying to achieve exactly, please explain.

Comment: I am using nginx to serve all my static files and use my node server to serve the remaining. I am just trying to get a grasp at what is actually happening in the configuration file

Comment: @suman Generally, NodeJS handles the static files itself and nginx is just used for reverse proxying, do not need a separate setup for that. There are many `static` middlewares to do that. What you are trying to do is also possible I think.